# HEAD detached at origin/master

Tags: git, github, versionamento

Comecei a estudar a pouco tempo, Git, e estava criando branch, mas acabei criando mais branch do que eu queria. Então, fui deletando os branch que eu não queria com a linha de comando:

Para apagar o branch localmente:
`git branch -D <nome do branch>`

Apaguei todos ficando só o master, porém apareceu o seguinte `branch 
HEAD detached at origin/master`

Alguém consegue me ajudar em me dizer o que devo fazer, ou melhor, no que eu fiz de errado?!

Comment: Tem o histórico de comandos? Pelo visto parece que foi algum checkout que deu errado...

Comment: Utilize `git branch` e verifique se você está no `master`, caso não esteja utilize `git checkout master`

Comment: Tinha criado branch fora da pasta que era pra ser criada. Por e tava dando git checkout master dentro da pasta! Não iria dar nunca! Valeu, galera pela contribuição.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente você não está na `branch` **`master`**, isso deverá resolver seu problema:

```
git checkout master
```